# How do we feel about pedagogical questions?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

By *pedagogical question* I mean an artificially-constructed question posed by a community member in order that he or she can then write a discussion, of the particular points raised by the question, in the guise of an answer.

[A question on AGPL interpretation](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/650/458) was asked by one of our users back in 2015, then shortly thereafter [answered](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/663/458) by another of our users.  Recently, yet another user came along and made a point in the comments field of that answer, the response to which caused first a comment discussion, then the creation of [first one](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/5003/458) and [then a second](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/5010/458) pedagogical question.

Personally, I'm very much enjoying the debate.  I think that both sides are making excellent points, reasonably respectfully, and it's given me much to think about.  But that's not my question.  What I want to know *here* is how the community feels about the practice of asking questions merely in order to promulgate one's viewpoint in the form of an answer (FAOD: I'm not conflating this with the normal business of asking a question that currently vexes me, discovering the answer by myself, then answering my earlier question to share the knowledge I have since discovered).  Are we OK with pedagogical questions, or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right at the top of the Stackexchange tour is this:

> We build libraries of high-quality questions and answers, focused on each community's area of expertise.

It seems to me that pedagogical questions fit that goal nicely.  Nothing in that vision statement says that the question has to be nonpedagogical.

Answer (score 2):

Self-answers are encouraged. It says it [right here, in the help center](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Whether the question is "artificially" constructed purely for the purpose of self-answering it or not, as long as it's good quality Q&A there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the perpetrator mentioned in the question. My take is that when these are properly crafted on-topic questions this is helpful and useful to the site and may help address some of the basic for visiting users. Yet I am open to not make such postings if this considered a problem.